# Error : alert box with no message displayed only in chrome

Tags: jquery

The below alert message is shown only in chrome.when I click ok in alert, then some buttons are not working. then I refresh the page its working. 
When I test in other browser its working well and no alerts there.

[image]

I was not able to find the root cause of this issue.
Anyone please help me.

Comment: what ?where ?when ?how ?

Comment: In mvc application,when I submit the form the above alert message is shown  in chrome browser. but everything is working in IE and other.

Comment: it that when you close the alert box by clicking ok.. the some of the buttons in your page stops working

Comment: @Transformer  yes.its working once refresh the whole page or I  reopen the page.

Comment: can i see your code how you called the alert box

Comment: since you are using jquery.. is that jquery dialog

Answer (score 0):

I think what might ease your problem is [jQuery BlockUI](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/).

Have a look at the [demo's](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#demos).

This supports all browser and it gives you more crazy option. But i'm still waiting to see your codes

or if you still want the normal alertbox in MVC applications http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/syedshakeer/how-to-show-alert-and-confirmation-message-box-in-Asp-Net/

i really hope it helps you out